# I am attempting to create a Todo list website, and I am currently stuck because I am unsure how to display the items and clear them

Tags: javascript, html

`I know that I need to create an li, and that's what I did but it still did not work. If you could help and explain, that would be awesome. Thank you

I did the html and css part, but the javascript always seems to get me confused. I know I need to create a list, but I'm not sure why and how to completely do it. this is my code

```
    <h1>To-Do List</h1>
    
        
         add item
         clear item
       

<body>
    <div class="ToDo">
        <h1>To-Do List</h1>
        <form>
            <input type="text" id="inputItem" name="submit" placeholder="add an item">
            <button onclick="addTask()"> add item</button>
            <button onclick="ClearTask()"> clear item</button>
          </form> 
          
    </div>
    <div>
        <ul id="list">
           

        </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="todo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


function addTask(){
    if(inputbox.value === " "){
    alert("Please enter something")
    }
    else{
        let li = document.createElement("li");
        li.innerHTML= inputbox.value;
        list.appendChild(li);
    }

}`
```

Comment: Your code is badly formatted. Please add the whole page's code.

Comment: You could find plenty of [tutorials](https://github.com/dwyl/javascript-todo-list-tutorial/blob/main/README.md) and [simple demos](https://codepen.io/franklynroth/pen/ZYeaBd) online. There are several approaches to implement this, and you might want to do more research

Answer (score 1):

The main problem in your JavaScript is you didn't include `getElementById()` to actually get the `inputItem` and `list` and you didn't define the `clearTasks()` function.

```js
function addTask() {
    var inputbox = document.getElementById("inputItem");
    var list = document.getElementById("list");

    if (inputbox.value === "") {
        alert("Please enter something");
    } else {
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.innerHTML = inputbox.value;
        list.appendChild(li);
    }
}

function clearTasks() {
    var list = document.getElementById("list");
    list.innerHTML = "";
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
      <div class="ToDo">
          <h1>To-Do List</h1>
          <form>
              <input type="text" id="inputItem" name="submit" placeholder="Add an item">
              <button type="button" onclick="addTask()">Add Item</button>
              <button type="button" onclick="clearTasks()">Clear Items</button>
          </form>
      </div>
      <div>
          <ul id="list">
          </ul>
      </div>
      <script src="todo.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

For these type of projects (like simple HTML, CSS and JS) you can checkout [CodePen](https://codepen.io) or any other live editors since they let you test your code functionality easily.

Here's a link to my [CodePen](https://codepen.io/ahmarzaidi/pen/dyQOJmj?editors=1010) where I've implemented the solution.

Comment: CodePen does not work well on mobile devices. The SO snippet functionality here would be slightly more user friendly in this respect.

Comment: Alright, I've added the code snippet. It's pretty convenient.